# How to use mocking to compare real results

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, python-unittest, pytest-mock

I have a sample class which reads a saved Tensorflow model and runs predictions

```
class Sample():
   ## all it does is creates a new column with predictions

   def __init__(self, tf_model):
      self.tf_model = tf_model

   def tf_process(self, x):

       ##some other preprocessing
       x["tf_predictions"] = self.tf_model.predict(x)
       return x
   
   def predict(self, x):
       predictions = self.tf_process(x)
       return predictions
```

Code for Unittesting without having to load the model:

```
import unittest
import pandas as pd
from unittest import TestCase, mock
from my_package.sample_model import Sample

class TestSample(unittest.TestCase):

   def test_predict(self):
      with mock.patch("Sample.tf_process") as process:
         process.return_value = pd.DataFrame("hardcoded_value")
         #to check: process.return_value = Output (Sample.predict())
```

Goal:

To compare `process.return_value` with the `Output of predict method in Sample`, but to do this I still have to load the model, I dont understand what is the use of `mock` here since i will have to anyway call the `predict` method to compare it with `process.return_value`. Any suggestions will be helpful

Comment: Well, it depends on what are you testing. If you want to test the prediction, you cannot mock it, that would defy the purpose. If you want to test `tf_process` without testing `predict`, mock `predict` instead. With your current mocking, you can only test that `predict` calls `tf_process` with the correct argument.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I just want to test if the column ```tf_predictions``` is created? Any suggestions on how to test that.

Comment: As I wrote - in this case you can mock `predict` (not sure which class it belongs) to return something sensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case it's better to use `Mock()`. You can create really good and simple tests without `patch()`. Just prepare all necessary mocked instances for initialization.

```
from unittest.mock import Mock


class TestSample(TestCase):
    def test_predict(self):
        # let's say predict() will return something... just an example
        tf = Mock(predict=Mock(return_value=(10, 20, 30)))
        df = pd.DataFrame({'test_col': (1, 2, 3)})
        df = Sample(tf).predict(df)
        # check column
        self.assertTrue('tf_predictions' in df.columns)
        # or check records
        self.assertEqual(
            df.to_dict('records'),
            [
                {'test_col': 1, 'tf_predictions': 10},
                {'test_col': 2, 'tf_predictions': 20},
                {'test_col': 3, 'tf_predictions': 30}
            ]
        )
```

Also it's really helps when you need tests for complex services. Just an example:

```
class ClusterService:
    def __init__(self, service_a, service_b, service_c) -> None:
        self._service_a = service_a
        self._service_b = service_b
        self._service_c = service_c
        # service_d, ... etc

    def get_cluster_info(self, name: str):
        self._service_a.send_something_to_somewhere(name)
        data = {
            'name': name,
            'free_resources': self._service_b.get_free_resources(),
            'current_price': self._service_c.get_price(name),
        }

        return ' ,'.join([
            ': '.join(['Cluster name', name]),
            ': '.join(['CPU', str(data['free_resources']['cpu'])]),
            ': '.join(['RAM', str(data['free_resources']['ram'])]),
            ': '.join(['Price', '{} $'.format(round(data['current_price']['usd'], 2))]),
        ])


class TestClusterService(TestCase):
    def test_get_cluster_info(self):
        cluster = ClusterService(
            service_a=Mock(),
            service_b=Mock(get_free_resources=Mock(return_value={'cpu': 100, 'ram': 200})),
            service_c=Mock(get_price=Mock(return_value={'usd': 101.4999})),
        )

        self.assertEqual(
            cluster.get_cluster_info('best name'),
            'Cluster name: best name ,CPU: 100 ,RAM: 200 ,Price: 101.5 $'
        )
```